# Is IBM Cloud available in China?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I plan to use IBM Cloud to deploy an application from Shanghai.

Is there any limitation for IBM Cloud in China? Can anyone confirm whether the platform is available without a VPN?

Answer (score 1):

IBM Cloud will totally work in China and it will work without VPN as well. The only thing probably need to noted is the closest IAAS data center is located in Japan. hope this help

Comment: Seems Hong Kong IAAS not work at all, something different for Japan IAAS?

Comment: @PlayKid, it depends on your definition of IAAS is. The HKG02 datacenter is still avaliable under "Classic Infrastructure" calegory == "legacy Softlayer" with more traditional offering. If you are looking for VPC feature then the datacenter are currently located in Dallas, Frankfurt, London, Sydney and Tokyo